# How to add ModelStateInvalidFilter as a global filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add `ModelStateInvalidFilter` as a global filter so that I don't have to add `ApiController` attribute on every controllers.

This is what I'm doing in my Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ApiBehaviorOptions>();
    services.AddScoped<ModelStateInvalidFilter>();

    services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.AddService<ModelStateInvalidFilter>())
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);                              
}
```

However, I'm getting this error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate  'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter'.

I know the generic `ILogger<T>` is automatically injected by the framework but how do I inject the non-generic `ILogger` which is a dependency of the `ModelStateInvalidFilter` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[ApiController]`, `ModelStateInvalidFilter` isn't resolved from the DI container, [it's created with `new`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs#L40):

```
_modelStateInvalidFilter = new ModelStateInvalidFilter(
    apiBehaviorOptions.Value,
    loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ModelStateInvalidFilter>());
```

In order to be able to resolve this from the DI container, we'll need to be a bit more explicit about how we create an instance of `ILogger`, which can be done when adding `ModelStateInvalidFilter` to the DI container, like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ModelStateInvalidFilter>(sp =>
{
    var loggerFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

    return new ModelStateInvalidFilter(
        sp.GetRequiredService<ApiBehaviorOptions>(),
        loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ModelStateInvalidFilter>());
    });
};
```

In this example, `sp` is the instance of `IServiceProvider` that we can use to request services from the DI container. `ILoggerFactory` has already been registered for us, so we can request it and use it in the same way shown in the first code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks this works. So I have to manually add the dependencies if I add `ModelStateInvalidFilter` as a global filter. But when I use `[ApiController]` attribute on a controller, what/where is adding all the dependencies?

Comment: `IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions>` is added [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L150) and `ILoggerFactory` is added [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L41).

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my question, how does adding `[ApiController]` automatically configure these dependencies? I tried to search the source code but couldn't find out how `ApiControllerAttribute` and the dependencies (`ApiBehaviorOptions` and `ILogger`) are related.

Comment: It doesn't. The two links I referenced in my first comment show where these are registered - if you use `IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions>` instead of just `ApiBehaviorOptions`, it should work without you doing any registration of your own. The link in the first line of my answer shows the class that does the real work here.